# RavedDB "outerjoin"

Tags: ravendb

I have 2 collections of documents in my ravenDB, location and address like this:

```
public class Location()
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<Address> Addresses{get;set;}

}

public class Address()
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string StreetName {get;set;}
    public string PostalCode {get;set;}
}
```

So a Location can have zero og many addresses. And I can have many addresses that are not assigned to a Location.

If I have data like this:

```
//2 Location document
{
Id:"Location/1",
Name: "My Location 1"
Addresses: [{id:"Address/1"},
            {id:"Address/2"}
            ]
}

{
Id:"Location/2",
Name: "My Location 2"
Addresses: [
            {id:"Address/2"}
            ]
}


//3 Address document
{
Id: "Address/1",
StreetName: "Street1 10",
PostalCode: "1000"
}

{
Id: "Address/2",
StreetName: "Street1 11",
PostalCode: "1000"
}

{
Id: "Address/3",
StreetName: "Street1 12",
PostalCode: "2000"
}
```

I'm struggleing to find the best way to create an index of this which will give me a resultset like this:

```
StreetAddress PostalCode    Location
Street1 10  1000    My Location 1
Street2 11  1000    My Location 2
Street2 11  1000    My Location 1
Street3 12  2000
```

I would appreciate any input on this:-)

Answer (score 1):

**One option** is to model the other way around, i.e.

```
public class Location()
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

}

public class Address()
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string StreetName {get;set;}
    public string PostalCode {get;set;}
    // Locations is a list with the Location documents IDs
    public List<string> Locations {get;set;}

}
```

And then the **index** can be:

```
from address in docs.Addresses
select new {
     StreetAddress = address.StreetName,
     PostalCode = address.PostalCode
}
```

And then use the following **Query**:

```
from index 'AddressesIndex' as x
load x.Locations as locations[]
select {
      StreetName: x.StreetName,
      PostalCode: x.PostalCode,
      Locations: locations.map(x => x.Name)
}
```

===========================================================================

**A second option** is to use the ***same models*** as you have in the question description
and define a 
*multi-map-reduce* index.

The *multi-map-reduce* index will be:

**The first map:**

```
from locationDoc in docs.Locations
from addressId in locationDoc.Addresses
let address = LoadDocument(addressId, "Addresses")
select new {
       StreetName = address.StreetName,
       PostalCode = (string)null,
       LocationNames = new []{locationDoc.Name},
}
```

**The second map:**

```
from address in docs.Addresses
select new{
       StreetName = address.StreetName,
       PostalCode = address.PostalCode,
       LocationNames = (string)null
}
```

**The reduce:**

```
from result in results
group result by new { result.StreetName } into g
select new {
       StreetName = g.Key.StreetName,
       PostalCode = g.Select(x => x.PostalCode).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
       LocationNames = g.SelectMany(x => x.LocationNames)
}
```

Comment: Thank you:-) I ended up with a multi-map-reduce index